# avoid RunsJob in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, sidekiq

I have a method that set delayed job after all:

```
def method
  ...
  RunsJob.set(wait_until: target_date).perform_later(id)
end
```

when I write spec I call **method** and get:

```
Failure/Error: RunsJob.set(wait_until: target_date).perform_later(id)

 NotImplementedError:
   Use a queueing backend to enqueue jobs in the future. Read more at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html
```

I use

```
gem 'sidekiq'

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-sidekiq'
end
```

How to pass test?

Comment: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing

Comment: Also this: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Active-Job

Comment: @SergioTulentsev unfortunately both guides doesn't help at all.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't tell me anything. I'm willing to bet that you _are_ missing some steps from ActiveJob guide.

Comment: both guides describe how to use sideq or ActiveJob in tests, and which tools they provide for testing Jobs.

But in my case I don't need to test Job, I only need to avoid errors

Comment: Have you done what the error message tells you to?

Comment: I am pretty sure you'll get the same error if you run that method outside of a test (normal execution).

Answer (score 0):

You have not set the proper queue adapter:

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
```

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Active-Job#active-job-setup